# Angular Typescript getter and setter returning Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, class, properties

I have a class where I require a property in that class to return a few fields in an object.
I've done this a few times in .Net, but in Angular, I'm battling with an "Undefined" being returned.

I can confirm that the properties(transLanguageId, transLangDesc, translation) is populated on the IBatchFile, but not coming back on the GET. Not even a console.log shows up in the GETTER. Not hitting the GETTER code I presume.

What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

model.ts

```
export class translationItem {  
  id: number;
  language: string;
  translation: string; 
}

export class IBatchFile {
  constructor(_transData: translationItem) {
    this._transData = new translationItem();
  }
  private _transData: translationItem;

  get transData(): translationItem {      
    this._transData.id = this.transLanguageId;
    this._transData.language = this.transLangDesc;
    this._transData.translation = this.translation;     
    return this._transData;
  };
  set transData(value: translationItem) {
     this._transData.id = value.id;
     this._transData.language = value.language;
     this._transData.translation = value.translation;
  };
  transLanguageId: number;
  transLangDesc: string;
  translation: string;
}
```

batchdocList.ts

```
private _batchFileListResults$ = new BehaviorSubject<IBatchFile[]>([]);

public loadDocList(batchid) {
  this.urlservice.getBatchFiles(batchid)         
  .subscribe(result => {      
    this._batchFileListResults$.next(result); //**result is of class IBatchFile**        

    this._batchFileListResults$.value.forEach(item => {          
      console.log(item.transData);  //**returns Undefined**
    });
}
```

url.service.ts

```
getBatchFiles(batchId: number) {             
        return this.dataservice.getBatchFiles(config.resources.Api.gatewayUri + config.resources.Api.getBatchFiles+"/"+batchId);
     }
```

data.service.ts

```
getBatchFiles(url:string): Observable<IBatchFile[]> {        
        return this.http.get<IBatchFile[]>(url)
        .pipe(map(response => response))
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that:

- you are using HttpClient (`@angular/common/http`):
- you have `class X`

you need to know that it to know that `http.get<X>` does not return an instance of `X` class.

The fields are correctly populated, but the prototype chain is not.
You can test it yourself (in your browser DevTools):

```
result.constructor  //ƒ Object()
```

Compare it with:

```
const x = new X();
x.constructor       //class X
```

Thus, any items that are placed on the objects prototype (like methods and get / set accessors) are missing in the result object.

In my project I restricted return types from HttpClient.get to types (`type X` instead of `class X`). As types are compiled away, you will avoid this kind of weirdness.

Alternatively, you can transform the output from HttpClient.get and instantiate real classes via contructor.

Comment: Hi, I used the "result" for simplicity for the example, but actually use the declared BehaviorSubject. I updated the code to show the declaration thereof and replacing the result with the behaviorSubject as the object array to iterate on. Yet it happens whether I use the "result" or the declared behaviorSubject. btw. Im using httpClient yes. All the data is present, except when I use the "GET".

Comment: Understood, but that does not change my answer. The object you believe to be an instance of IBatchFile does not have prototype chain set up, and therefore is missing methods and accessors. Have you made the check I described?

Comment: I think I'm following you. So I added some more code to show how the data is mapped in the data.service.ts

Comment: `.pipe(map(response => response))` is not doing anything, but it is the right place to set a breakpoint to inspect the data, and to add mapping to classes if you need that

Comment: So I eventually created the object inside the model in the webApi and made sure all webApi returned items in the model had the same names and were present in the angular model. I am now more aware of the mapping as I did not know about this prototype object. Took a while, but thank you for pointing in right direction. Also, understand that should it not have the same names, to actually map them on the Angular side.