# 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Contact[]'

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript, angular-promise

I am already tried everything there on internet,and on stackoverflow I couldn't find the right answer. this is my first project in angular along with mongodb. But i am getting this error "Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Contact[]'." Can you see to it how can i solve this problem.
**contact.service.ts**

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

    @Injectable()
    export class ContactService {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      getContacts()
      {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts')
        .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
      }

      addContact(newContact)
      {
        var headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/contact', newContact, {headers:headers})
        .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
      }
      deleteContacts(id)
      {
        return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/contact'+id)
        .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()));
      }
    }
```

**contacts.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {ContactService} from '../contact.service';
    import {Contact} from '../contact';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-contacts',
      templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
      providers: [ContactService]
    })
    export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {

      contact:Contact;
      contacts:Contact[];
      first_name:string;
      last_name:string;
      phone:string;
      constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { 
        var contacts;
      }

      
      ngOnInit() {
        this.contactService.getContacts()
          .subscribe(contacts =>
            this.contacts = contacts);
      }

    }
```

**contact.ts**

```
    export class Contact{
        _id: string;
        first_name: string;
        last_name: string;
        phone:string;
    }
```

Comment: What is `this.contacts`? Presumably you're using TypeScript for the strong typing, in which case you don't want to be inventing vars on the fly at runtime: define that var in your constructor, and type it appropriately?

Comment: Can you show us what your contact.service.ts file looks like?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as image

Comment: now i have uploaded the code can you see to it. @Lesiak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getContacts method is implemented incorrectly.
The inferred type with your implementation is `Observable<Promise<any>>`, which causes a problem in a component using the method.

Change your code to:

```
getContacts(): Observable<Contact[]> {
  return this.http.get<Contact[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/contacts');
}
```

Read Angular manual on Http: [Requesting a typed response](https://angular.io/guide/http#typed-response)

Also, change Contact from class to interface or type. See [common pitfall when using http client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63504670/1570854)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to obtain an array of object directly from a Promise. You have to do this:

```
response.json().then(data => {

  let contacts : Contact[] = JSON.parse(js);
});
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you but i am totally new to this, like i started all this today only. so can you  elaborate pls.